# Can mattermost interactive dialog menu get dynamic values while it is open?

Tags: python, mattermost

I have 2 dropdown menu in dialog menu. User's first dropdown menu selection should efect the second dropdown menus options.

For example user's first choice is gitlab project's name second dropdown is that project's branchs. I set dropdown menus with creating array and set the option value to that array. I didn't use datasource because it can be use only for channels or users. As i understand once dialog is created it's values can not be changed.

is there a way to achive that?

```
  [{
        "display_name": "Project Name",
        "name": "Project_name",
        "type": "select",
        "options": project_option_array
  },
  {
        "display_name": "Branch",
        "name": "branch",
        "type": "select",
        "options": branch_option_array
  },],
```

Comment: dropdown as in GUI or in web?

Comment: GUI .i installed on mac with following https://docs.mattermost.com/install/desktop.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it does not at current time. Hope it can be done